# Improving my linq to object performance

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq to object method and I will call it thousands of times in my code. I was wondering is something can suggest any way I may improve it's performance even further.

I tried `.AsParallel()` but this throws an exception that I do not quite understand nor can find any useful information about online.

Here is my code:

```
public static    Func<List<Item>, Item,bool, Item > FetchItemFromItemListFucn =
(itemlist,  itemfofind, HaOrders) =>

(from s in itemlist
where  s.Orders.Any() == HaOrders && s.part1==itemfofind.part1  && s.part2==itemfofind.part2  &&
s.part3==itemfofind.part3  && s.part4==itemfofind.part4  &&
s.part5==itemfofind.part5  && s.part6==itemfofind.part6  &&
s.part7==itemfofind.part7  && s.part8==itemfofind.part8  


select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Do you currently have a performance problem with this code, or are you doing premature optimization? How fast is it, and how fast should it minimally be?

Comment: What does this function do?

Comment: Well this code is part of a larger code and will be called thousands of times so every bit of tuning is highly welcomed. The larger program does have some performance issue. I have identified this bit as the one that has the highest iterations number

Comment: I see some potential problems with the design.  Your `itemfofind` parts should probably be in their own collection, not as individual fields.

Comment: What types are the parts?

Comment: This function searches a list of items by matching a number of key as shown in the code. It is part of copying a dataset based on a number of keys and a file backup of a similar dataset

Comment: Did you *intentionally* limit yourself to 8 keys?

Comment: yes my key set is 8 from each row.

Comment: Does `Orders.Any()` trigger any database calls?

Comment: Oh, I see.  They *all* have to match.  Have you tried mashing the 8 keys together and putting them in a dictionary, or a lookup table with an index?  The resulting comparison is `O(1)`.

Comment: Robert, could you elaborate?

Comment: No database call, only linq to object.

Comment: `Where s.part1 + s.part2 + ... + s.part8 = MyHashTableKey`

Comment: Oh i see, this is a very good idea and i have considered it. Could you explain why this will yield performance gain?

Comment: Because hashtable is `O(1)`, and your comparisons are more or less `O(n)`.

Comment: Let us know how it worked out.

Comment: i will, by the way, why can't i use .AsParallel()?

Comment: You won't need `AsParallel` if you write a better function. `AsParallel` is for splitting long-running work into separate threads; it won't work here.

Comment: Can you share the error you get when using AsParallel?

Comment: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. 
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetTable(MetaTable metaTable)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetTable(Type type)